# Issues with unchecked generics

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I have a method  that is throws the following warning when compiled:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter of     
type TableColumn<ObservableList,?>[]   tableview.getColumns().addAll(Col);
```

I know that if the method is safe, I can add the @SafeVarargs annotation to suppress the warning. However, I'm not certain that my method is safe. Also, when I added the annotation (just to see what might happen), the compiler gave me the following error:

```
Invalid SafeVarargs annotation. Method InsertSQL(TableView<ObservableList>) 
is not a varargs method.
public TableView InsertSQL(TableView<ObservableList> tableview)
```

Here is the method in question, in its entirety:

```
private TableColumn<ObservableList, String> Col; //declared outside the   
method at the beginning of the class.

@SafeVarargs
public TableView InsertSQL(TableView<ObservableList> tableview) {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnCheck, user, password);
        SysList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(SysTableCall);
        SysData = st.executeQuery();

        for (int i = 0; i < SysData.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            Col = new TableColumn<>(SysData.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            Col.setCellValueFactory(new CallbackImpl(j));
            //Col.setEditable(true);
            if (i == 0) {
                Col.setPrefWidth(344);
                Col.setText("Record Number");
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                Col.setPrefWidth(344);
                Col.setText("Description");
            }
            tableview.getColumns().addAll(Col); //warning found on this line
        }

        while (SysData.next()) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int x = 1; x <= SysData.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); x++) {
                row.add(SysData.getString(x));
            }
            SysList.add(row);
        }
        tableview.setItems(SysList);
        st.execute();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement st1 = conn.prepareStatement(SysTableCheck);
            st.setString(1, RecCode);
            ResultSet tempData = st1.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(tempData.toString());
            //Logger.getLogger(SysInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(SysInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    }
    return tableview;
}
```

I'm using Java 8u40, and Netbeans 8.0.2. Ideally, I'd like to handle to warning (rather than suppress it). Thank you.

Comment: Arrays and generics don't mix.  Do you *have* to use an array?

Comment: What do you think `@SafeVarargs` does?  Just from the name _varargs_ and from the error message _is not a varargs method._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling varargs methods with generic instances leads to these warnings due to problems with arrays and generics. In your case simply use the `add` method instead of `addAll` with one argument.

Comment: And remove `@SafeVarargs` from `public TableView InsertSQL(TableView<ObservableList> tableview)` after having read [Annotation Type SafeVarargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html).

Comment: The annotation was merely there to demonstrate the error. But yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises from a number of different levels.

The `addAll(...)` method you're invoking is a method declared in `ObservableList`:

**`Interface ObservableList<E>`**

`public boolean addAll(E... elements)`

([see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll-E...-))

The problem arises if `E` is a generic type, as in your case, where `E` is `TableColumn<ObservableList<?>, String>`. Passing a list of the correct type of table columns into this method is not type-safe without knowing the implementation of the method, because the compiler converts your comma-delimited list of `TableColumn<ObservableList<?>, String>` to an array of those objects, and (essentially since arrays a covariant, i.e. `String[]` is a subclass of `Object[]`), the implementation of the method can execute well-meaning code that silently violates the type-safety of the generic type. The [documentation linked by Ivo Mori](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) shows an example.

Here's another:

```
public class A<T> {

    public void doBadThings(T... things) {
        if (things.length > 0) {
            Object[] array = things ; // not a problem, whatever T is all Ts are Objects
            array[0] = "oops" ; // this is fine, assigning a String to an Object
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<Integer> a = new A<>();
        Integer answer = 42 ;
        a.doBadThings(answer);
    }
}
```

In this case, the code compiles but fails with an `ArrayStoreException`, because it tries to store a `String` in an `Integer[]`.

The case you have is slightly more subtle, because the type parameter is itself a generic type, and is essentially the case shown in the `@SafeVarargs` documentation.

The `@SafeVarargs` annotation on a method is a signal that the method is written in a way that guarantees no type-safety violations will occur. If a method contains this annotation, then invoking it with generic types will not generate a compiler warning. Typically, if the method does not modify the content of the array, then it is safe. One concrete example of this is the [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) method. This method just takes a varargs of type `T` and returns a `List<T>`. Since the compiler will guarantee the only things of the correct type are passed into the method, and the method itself makes no changes to the values passed in, the method guarantees that it is typesafe, and so is annotated `@SafeVarargs`.

Unfortunately, since `ObservableList` is an interface, it cannot possibly make any guarantees about the implementation of the `addAll` method (since implementations are deferred to implementing classes).

My personal preference in this situation is to either use repeated calls to the `add` method taking a single element, or pass multiple elements to `Arrays.asList` (which is safe) and then pass the result to the overloaded method `ObservableList.addAll(Collection)` (which is also safe, since it doesn't use varargs, or arrays):

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<?>, String> col1 = ... ;
TableColumn<ObservableList<?>, String> col2 = ... ;
table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(col1, col2));
```

Comment: I want to thank you for the very detailed answer, and while the other answer was sufficient to solve the problem, I appreciate gaining a deeper understanding into why.